# Is there a version of Chrome or Chromium whose bookmarks are visible to the HUD?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, hud

I noticed that Firefox has bookmarks that can be executed in the HUD. Love it!

Chrome and Chromium, which run javascript apps much faster for some odd reason, allow for history to be called through the HUD, but not bookmarks. This wouldn't be a problem if ALL history was callable, but it seems that Chrome LIMITS the amount of history visible to the hud.

Is there a version of chrome or chromium that will see our bookmarks?

Answer (score 9):

Earlier versions of Chromium did have the bookmarks and full history exposed to the application menu and the HUD.  The Chromium developers felt that Dbusmenu's implementation slowed their startup time too much, so they disabled it.

Since then we've drastically improved the speed of Dbusmenu requests, so it shouldn't be an issue, but someone needs to work with them to restore the feature in Chromium.

- http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/

Comment: Cool. So maybe someday there will be an answer to this, but it looks like not anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

The HUD (at least in 12.04) simply provides access to the same items provided in the menus at the top of the application. (The menus accessed by moving the mouse to the top panel.)

In Firefox, there is a Bookmarks menu - this means your bookmarks are also accessible through the HUD.

In Chromium, there is no Bookmarks menu. The bookmarks menu is instead accessed via the wrench. This is why your bookmarks are not available in the HUD.

Comment: Irony it is, Try searching Tools in Chrome HUD , it gives appropriate results from the *wrench* submenus which is similar to bookmarks *Wrench* , then why Bookmarks is **exception.**